# FreeBSD: Newbie Install Questions

Tags: installation, freebsd

I need some up to date information on how to set up a RAID-1 / RAID-Stripe when installing a new version of FreeBSD. I have several Pentium 2/3/4 computer that I need to install a os onto. But also several Sun Blade 100 that is still in good condition. Most of the computers have matching harddrives so I would like to run some kind of RAID on them.

Something Equal to LVM2 that is used under Linux would be great also.

Don't think I haven't read the handbook because I have with a fine tooth comb.

At the local library I only have old worthless books so no help there...

Any way you can help I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

The book you want is by Michael W. Lucas - called "Absolute FREEBSD" (mine is 2nd edition).  On page 545 the topic is "Striping Disks" using the gstripe kernel loadable module.  It's a gold-mine reference book if you're doing FreeBSD admin.  I used it to set up both RAID0 and RAID1 and the book made it easy. (gmirror is the other KLM you may want to look at)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to mirror using the pair of matching drives in each machine, I recommend you install to one of the devices and mirror it to the 2nd device after the install.  The FreeBSD handbook covers [RAID1](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/geom-mirror.html) in this scenario.

Comment: @Gioff: Just a nit-pick but he said stripe - not mirror, and there's a BIG difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the FreeBSD Handbook...
its a truly great, free and up to date reference. Of course it also explains how to set up a raid.
Of particular interest to you:

[GEOM](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/geom-intro.html)

[Raid 1 - Mirror](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/geom-mirror.html)